# Can someone tell me where is it picking images from?

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface

```
package demo;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/*`enter code here`
 * ComboBoxDemo.java uses these additional files:`enter code here`
 *   images/Bird.gif
 *   images/Cat.gif
 *   images/Dog.gif
 *   images/Rabbit.gif
 *   images/Pig.gif
 */
public class Demo extends JPanel
implements ActionListener {
    JLabel picture;

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    public Demo() {
        super(new BorderLayout());

        String[] petStrings = { "Bird", "Cat", "Dog", "Rabbit", "Pig" };

        //Create the combo box, select the item at index 4.
        //Indices start at 0, so 4 specifies the pig.
        JComboBox petList = new JComboBox(petStrings);
        petList.setSelectedIndex(4);
        petList.addActionListener(this);

        //Set up the picture.
        picture = new JLabel();
        picture.setFont(picture.getFont().deriveFont(Font.ITALIC));
        picture.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        updateLabel(petStrings[petList.getSelectedIndex()]);
        picture.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,0,0,0));

        //The preferred size is hard-coded to be the width of the
        //widest image and the height of the tallest image + the border.
        //A real program would compute this.
        picture.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(177, 122+10));

        //Lay out the demo.
        add(petList, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(picture, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20,20,20,20));
    }

    /** Listens to the combo box. */
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
        String petName = (String)cb.getSelectedItem();                                                          
        updateLabel(petName);
    }

    protected void updateLabel(String name) {
        ImageIcon icon = createImageIcon("images/" + name + ".png");
        picture.setIcon(icon);
        picture.setToolTipText("A drawing of a " + name.toLowerCase());
        if (icon != null) {
            picture.setText(null);
        } else {
            picture.setText("Image not found");
        }
    }

    /** Returns an ImageIcon, or null if the path was invalid. */
    protected static ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path) {
        java.net.URL imgURL = Demo.class.getResource(path);
        if (imgURL != null) {
            return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ComboBoxDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        JComponent newContentPane = new Demo();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);


        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the code i have got from oracle but i don't know where it would need to pick images from because every time i create a source folder with images, it still wouldn't pick it up. Or if you could tell me which part of the code is picking the image up? I need to use same kinda code for my work.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Create an `images` folder in your `user.dir` and put the images in there. You can see what the `user.dir` is printing out `System.getProperty("user.dir")`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder named `images` in the same folder where your `Demo.java` is. And place your images there. The image names, according to your code, are "Bird.png", "Cat.png", "Dog.png", "Rabbit.png", "Pig.png".

So your project structure is something like this:

```
demo
    src
    └───demo
        │   Demo.java
        └───images
                Bird.png
                Cat.png
                Dog.png
                Rabbit.png
                Pig.png
```

Comment: What do you mean by "wouldn't work"? Did you place your java file and the images folder inside a folder named `demo`?

Comment: I wish i could post the screenshot here but yes i have main project name Demo and under that i have two folders names as src which has the demo.java and images folder that holds the images that are supposed to be displayed in png format. Thanks

Comment: Then remove the first line that says `package demo;`. That should solve your problem.

Comment: tried that too and it gave me this error
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

 at demo.Demo.main(Demo.java:98)"

Comment: edit your question and add an sceenshot of your project structure. Your code runs fine here on my machine.

Comment: i have added the screenshot now, you can have a look please. thanks

Comment: like I said, place your images folder inside the **inner** `demo` folder.

Comment: i dont know what you mean by that as y i try creating an image source folder, it will put it there automatically. Can you plz tell me the hierarchy of where you have put the images folder?

Comment: aww saw that but that wouldn't work either :( thanks for your help mate.

Comment: then I would suggest you start a different project with a name other than `demo`. I don't know what mysteries is causing it not to work in your computer. It is all well here. Remember to follow the same hierarchy I have shown here.

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageIcon icon = createImageIcon("images/" + name + ".png");
```

This line is providing image path which is `images/name.png` and value of `name` could be among these `{"Bird", "Cat", "Dog", "Rabbit", "Pig"}`

```
picture.setIcon(icon);
```

The above line is setting the `icon` to `JLabel` `picture`.

Create a folder named `images` in root directory of the project and put all `.png` images in `images` folder.

Answer (score 0):

See: http://www.thinkplexx.com/learn/howto/java/system/java-resource-loading-explained-absolute-and-relative-names-difference-between-classloader-and-class-resource-loading

I finally found out where the problem lies, but I cannot understand why they way Oracle made the code doesn't work.

Go back to the original code published at 
https://www.codetantra.com/java/jdk6.0/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/ComboBoxDemoProject/src/components/ComboBoxDemo.java

You need to go to the folder where your project is. You will see:
bin
images
src

The images folder may have all the expected image files in it, but the program does not get to them somehow. Copy the gif files into the folder that holds bin, images, and src.

You will now see:
bin
images
src
Bird.gif
Cat.gif
and so forth.

Now go back and change Oracle's code:

//    ImageIcon icon = createImageIcon("images/" + name + ".gif"); //This way does not work.

to

```
    ImageIcon icon = createImageIcon(name + ".gif");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to debug where the program fetches the files, you could use the following creating a `File` object and requesting it's absolute path.

[**Ideone**](https://ideone.com/flucSP)

```
System.out.println(new File("images/Bird.png").getAbsolutePath()); // C:\... or /...
```